# Single Sign-On Marketing Cloud with ADFS as Identity Provider

Tags: marketing-cloud, single-sign-on

Recently, I have configured SSO with ADFS for the Service Cloud and now I am trying to achieve the same thing for the Marketing Cloud. However, I do not want Salesforce Service Cloud as Identity Provider, but ADFS. I can paste the metadata from the identity provider into a key in the Marketing Cloud but the link will not work. I have also read all the documentation about SSO for the Marketing Cloud, but everything is focused on SF as identity provider or it tells me to use JSON message (which I don't understand). Can someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: I believe you need to be clear on what you are asking. Do you want to use Windows Active directory federation services as Identity provider so that you can log in automatically to SFMC when you open the browser and navigate to you SMFC URL? As far as I know, if you have SAML metadata from your IdP, you can enable SSO in SFMC. Are you able to get SAML metadata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the account your are looked onto e.g. Windows has an integrated SFMC user account.

Go to SFMC > Admin > Users and ensure your account is integrated for SSO.

Also check under Admin > Security and ensure SSO is enabled (there's a tick box to tick).

When I get in front of my account I'll update with screenshots. I've done a few SSO with SAML (SecureAuth) so it does work

Comment: Thank you, I got it working. I received an incorrect metadata file, so that's why I received an error that the signature was not signed.

Comment: @IvorBergmans This is quite old, however I was wondering if you could share some details on how you configured the claim rules in ADFS. Thanks!